# Powerpoint Presentation on the Mobile Phones?

Tags: mobile, powerpoint-services

Want to display the Powerpoint Presentation on the Mobile, let me know if it can be achieved in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If available Office Web Apps will let you natively open and present a PowerPoint presentation.  If you don't need to keep this "in house" you can leverage it via SkyDrive (Microsoft has Office Web Apps integrated with SkyDrive).

SharePoint 2010 Enterprise also contains the same PowerPoint functionality without Office Web Apps.

Comment: Unable to access the skydrive from Windows Mobile 6.1.4 Emulator..Should I need to install any apps?

Comment: I don't think you will find much support for any of MS latest for WinMo6.  Your best bet is probably to export PPT as images, and then use a brief bit of JavaScript to cycle thru them on mouse clicks. Something like this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-presentation-slides-with-html-and-css-2/

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure, if you create a SharePoint page using page viewer webpart by following this [Tutorial](https://www.acceleratedk.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=13), you will be able to view it on mobile as power point presentation as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Without PowerPoint app service you can't access the PPT on the page viewer webpart